# Get rid of unnecessary spaces from Format-Table output of array properties

Tags: arrays, powershell, format

In many cases an object in Powershell 5.1 can have a property that is an array. And the main issue is that it is not in the end (for example we have 2 such properties, so anyway one of them will be not in the end).
For example

```
(Get-Process)[0] | Format-Table Name,Threads,Handles

Name Threads                       Handles
---- -------                       -------
Code {6212, 10164, 10804, 5260...}     238
```

I tried to make a normal table from that output:

```
(Get-Process)[0] |
    Select-Object Name, @{ l = 'Threads'; e = { $_.Threads.ID -join "`n" } }, Handles |
    Format-Table -Wrap

Name Threads                             Handles
---- -------                             -------
Code 6212                                    238
     10164
     10804
     5260
     716
     9120
     6336
```

But as you can see it adds "additional" spaces at the array column. As I understand these spaces are the length of the array

```
((Get-Process)[0].Threads.ID -join "").Length
```

Can I eliminate these exessive spaces in the output?
Because if I have dozens of elements in array, I can't see last columns.

By the way "Out-String -Width" doesn't help either:

```
(Get-Process)[0] |
    Select-Object Name, @{ l='Threads';e={$_.Threads.ID | Out-String -Width 12 }}, Handles |
    Format-Table -Wrap
```

-Autosize make no difference.

And Width parameter make the situation worse:

```
(Get-Process)[0] |
Select-Object Name, @{ l = 'Threads'; e = { $_.threads.ID -join "`n" } }, Handles | 
Format-Table -Wrap @{ e='Name'; width = 4} ,@{ e='Threads';width = 12}, Handles

Name Threads                                                  Handles
---- -------                                                  -------
Code 6212                                                     238    
     10164
     10804
     5260
     716
     9120
     6336
```

Comment: Instead of `Format-Table` you can use `Out-GridView`

Comment: `(Get-Process)[0] | Select-Object Name, handles, @{ l = 'Threads'; e = { $_.Threads.ID -join "\`n" } } | Format-Table -Wrap`    ....  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf No, it doesn't work. As I wrote I have 2 such properties. And they can't be at last position at the same time

Comment: [1] never use any `Format-*` cmdlet for anything other than FINAL output to the screen OR a file. [*grin*] ///// [2] the  width of a column is calculated on the ... width of the content of the column. your column is just plain text **_and the string in that location is just a string with the column width derived from the length of that string._** ///// if you want a custom layout, you will need to build it using a custom format. take a look at `Format-Custom` and `Update-FormatData` for more info.

Comment: Yes, this is the main goal - preserve the object, but let the operator to see what's going on. So it is definitely the right case.

Comment: I've found, that I can specify width parameter for every column on every format-table property. This solution isn't elegant and absolutely counterintuitive. And I still have to figure out how to get this width, for every property.